# Do i need to make new branch for bug fix or work on master branch in git

Tags: git, version-control

I have the three branches one is

```
master
develop
release-1
```

There is some template alignment issue which is showing out of format data. I want to know that should i checkout master branch , then edit the file and them commit on master branch and then update the prod server.

or i need to make new branch `bugfix` do some changes there and then merge with all branches

thats looks to me time wasting as , i only may have 5-6 lines to fix the code.

But i was just consdering the best practices

Comment: The "answer" is whatever your organization decides is a good work-flow. Anything else is opinion-polling.

Comment: @CodeGnome i am the single coder here so i need to decide. i want to follow best practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are the single programmer working on this do not make your life more complicated than it needs to be.

Branching and merging have a practical place in a multi developer environment.  If you are working alone, the one use they really have is for "experimentation".

There is nothing wrong with working on master and only branching when you want to experiment.

It is also very common to have a develop branch and merge to master.

Many more branches than that and you are probably complicating things for yourself.   Remember it's supposed to make your life easier, not harder.

Answer (score 4):

Good practice is to fix bugs on their own branch and then have your code reviewed before having it merged back into master.